# How to prove the equality $a_n = n^2$ for every $n$, if $n \in \mathbb N$?

Tags: induction

Given sequence $a_1, a_2, ...$ where $a_1=1, a_2 = 4, a_3 = 9$ and when $n > 3, a_n = a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+a_{n-3} + 2(2n-3)$. Prove that the equality $a_n = n^2$ is valid for every $n$if $n \in \mathbb N$

I am pretty sure I have to use strong induction here, but I'm not sure how to solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guide:

- Verify that $a_n=n^2$ holds for $n \in \{ 1,2,3\}$.
- Simplify $a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\color{red}{+}a_{n-3}+2(2n-3)=(n-1)^2-(n-2)^2\color{red}{+}(n-3)^2+2(2n-3)$ and show that it is equal to $n^2$.

Credit:

Special thanks to Rene Schipperus for pointing out the mistake in the question and Donald Splutterwit  for fixing the mistake.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the question since that expression is not $n^2$.

Comment: Hmm.... you are right. The coefficient of $n^2$ is $-n^2$

Comment: How can we simplify that $a_{n-1}-a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}+2(2n-3)=(n-1)^2-(n-2)^2 + (n-3)^2+2(2n-3)$?

Comment: Try expanding the right hand side and cancel out terms. Potential useful formula $(a-b)^2=a^2-b^2-2ab$, $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: I meant how did you get to $(n-1)^2$ from $a_{n-1}$?

Comment: I see, induction hypothesis, we are going to assume $a_k = k^2$ for all $k < n$. hence we have $a_{n-1}=(n-1)^2$.

Comment: Yes, that was the breaking point for me, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The second minus sign in the question should be a plus. $a_n = a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\color{red}{+}a_{n-3} + 2(2n-3)$, it is then quite easy to show by using strong induction.

Comment: phew, you saved the day.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, my bad. How could I solve it though?

Comment: Sorry, its correct.

Comment: $1-4+9-6=0$ ... I get the constant term cancelling out ... as required. @ReneSchipperus

Comment: [wolfram alpha verification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(n−1)%5E2−(n−2)%5E2%2B(n−3)%5E2%2B2(2n−3)) Awesome correction.